# C gameloop: UI + logic separation and adding AI player

Tags: c, game-loop

I'm writing a university game project in C. Second player can be both human and PC (using minimax), UI should be possible through both CLI and GUI (SDL).

Before writing any implementation, I'm trying to figure out how the `main()` function should look, and mostly what the game loop should or shouldn't include.

I came up with the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    UIManager *uiManager = UIManager_Create(argc, argv);
    GameManager *gameManager = GameManager_Create();
    UserCommand *command;
    while (1) {
        command = UIManager_ProcessInput(uiManager);
        GameManager_ProcessCommand(gameManager, command);
        UIManager_Render(uiManager, gameManager->gameState);
    }
    UIManager_Destroy(uiManager);
    GameManager_Destroy(gameManager);
    return 0;
}
```

Where `UIManager` will have:

```
UIManager* UIManager_Create(int argc, char *argv[]);
void UIManager_Destroy(UIManager *manager);
UserCommand* UIManager_ProcessInput(UIManager *manager);
void UIManager_Render(UIManager *manager, const GameState *gameState);
```

And will trigger CLI or GUI modules, depending on the `argv[]` value.

The `GameManager` will hold the game status and will update it according to the `UserCommand`.

I have two main concerns, mostly in terms of SW design:

1. I order to `UIManager_Render()`, the `UIManager` will have to be familiar with the game state. But this doesn't feels right to pass a `GameManager` instance to it, as the UI and logic should be separated as possible, shouldn't they? So I thought about creating another `GameState` "object", a header-only module which include only the definitions which the `GameManager` will update and the `UIManager` will render. Does that sounds correct? What is ideal way of dealing with what I'm asking?
2. I need to support an AI player (optional, the game might be between two human players as well), but I currently don't see how this adds up to my current app flow. On the one side, I shouldn't `UIManager_ProcessInput()` when there's an AI player. On the other hand, I don't think I should "dirty" the game loop with these concerns. But putting this kind of logic in `GameManager`/`UIManager` will again, make them dependent on each other. Again, what is the convention to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you writing all these from scratch? Specifically, the UI stuff?

Comment: Yes, both the logic and GUI (CLI + SDL) modules. Basically everything. I'm working through a set of instructions (requirements, not implementation instructions) of course.

Comment: Right. What are you using for GUI design? Regarding your design, it looks pretty fine except that `while(1){}`. How do you exit from that?

Comment: I haven't started it yet, but I don't have much restrictions about GUI. Just have to use SDL. I though about handling exiting inside `ProcessCommand()`, but I don't mind keeping a `gameManager->toExit` flag and test that in the `while` condition. Why is it preferable, though?

Comment: Well, considering that you are using some library to handling UI (graphical or text), there'll be some kind-of event loop there already. So, you would be using that loop and dispatching your events to it and that'd be responsible to update the UI accordingly. And, the exit sequence would be there too. So, you'd be left only to implement that game logic and that's it.

Comment: That's assuming the game only have GUI mode, but one can invoke it in CLI mode. That's why I created `UIManager` from the beginning. Also, SDL does seem to have a traditional gameloop, but I'm thinking about "breaking" in order to create one "flow", instead of both CLI gameloop and SDL gameloop.

Comment: Not only for GUI but text-based UI also. Take a look at ncurses library, for example. If SDL has one, you should make use of that also. What I wanted to say is that you should not reinvent the wheel. If you can make use of existing solution then you must use those. You would be focusing on your business logic (i.e. your game play only). You should plan for these things from the start. Best of luck! :)

Comment: You mentioned two players. Is there always two players taking turns?

Comment: One player is always human of course. The second can be either human or AI, the user will be able to choose it on the main menu.